# Download files from iCloud

Tags: swift, download, icloud

I have a problem when I download files from iCloud in my app.
The problem appears only at first launch after installation or if I add a file to iCloud from a different device.
As I start the app for the first time, I get all files (all pdf files) with the extension .pdf.icloud.
I think they are metadata files created by iCloud.
When I launch the app the second time all files get downloaded properly.
I haven’t found a solution yet, every help would be really appreciated.

This is the code I use to download files saved to iCloud.

```
func copyFileToLocal() {

    if isCloudEnabled() {

        deleteFilesInDirectory(url: DocumentsDirectory.localDocumentsURL)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: DocumentsDirectory.iCloudDocumentsURL!.path)

        while let file = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
            print(file)
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: DocumentsDirectory.iCloudDocumentsURL!.appendingPathComponent(file), to: DocumentsDirectory.localDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent(file))
                try fileManager.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: DocumentsDirectory.iCloudDocumentsURL!.appendingPathComponent(file))


                print("Moved to local dir")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Failed to move file to local dir : \(error)")
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I tried using only the first try statement or the second one, but they both don't work.
The best solution yet is to use them both, but the problem persists.

Comment: Many fail to mention where they use their code.

Comment: You should wait for the files to be downloaded completely before copying the documents to your local directory. Your code seems to be copying the item to local directory before the download from iCloud is even initiated.

Comment: I think `.pdf.icloud` files (prefixed with a `.` ) are how macOS represents files not currently downloaded.